# Keyboard shortcut to toggle spellcheck in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, spell-check

I frequently turn on and off the spellchecker in Chrome.

This is done by bringing up the context menu by *right-clicking in the text area > Spell check > Use basic spellcheck.*

Also, you have to make sure you don't happen to right-click on a misspelled word, because then you get the context menu for correcting the spelling instead.

I would like some way to have a keyboard shortcut for turning the spellchecker on and of. It could be a hack, or programmatically, via some browser extension, or whatever works.

Edit: My platform is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing so...

Comment: What platform ?

Comment: @Tetsujin, Platform is Ubuntu 20.04, if that is of any help.

Comment: Not to me personally, but to anyone who knows Ubuntu ;) People tend to assume Win if no platform is mentioned. Mac has a global keyboard shortcut structure which could easily do this, I don't think Win or nix has an equivalent, but let's see if someone comes up with something. Wish you luck..

Comment: Is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> good enough  as an answer or not?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, i guess you mean bringing up the context menu (not sure what you mean by Shift+F though) and then press S and then U ? That would work if it wasn't for the problem that the context menu looks different if the cursor happens to be on a misspelled word (which is often the case when you realize you want to turn off the spellcheck).

Comment: I meant bringing the context menu via Shift+F10 then pressing S follow by U.